# Contenteditable in HTML tables

Tags: html, html-table, contenteditable

With the code:

```
<table>
<tr><td contenteditable>My_Name</td><td>Surname</td></tr>
<tr><td contenteditable>My_Name2</td><td>Surname2</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can edit a cell in an HTML table. My problem is when I edit the cell and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, it creates a new line in cell. What I really would like is, if I press enter I go to the cell just below that cell I just edited so that I can edit that cell.

Currently I have to use the mouse to go to the next cell, but if I can press <kbd>enter</kbd> and go to the cell, it will help me edit the cells a bit faster. Plus the updated data will be stored in my database, so I also don't want unnecessary space stored in the database.

But I am not sure what I can do. Is there any example I can look at?

Comment: Read the keyboard for 'enter' key, javascript it to 'escape' the edition by setting focus somewhere else, perhaps the next td.

Comment: @Vanda, did any of the responses answer your question?

Comment: @NickG This is Jason Samuels's question.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This code requires JQuery.

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/v2Tdn/3/

```js
$('td').keypress(function (evt) {
    if (evt.which == 13) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var cellindex = $(this).index()
        // get next row, then select same cell index
        var rowindex = $(this).parents('tr').index() + 1
        $(this).parents('table').find('tr:eq(' + rowindex + ') td:eq(' + cellindex + ')').focus()
    }
})
```

*** UPDATE ***

Note, I've updated the jsfiddle to also select the text when you press <kbd>enter</kbd>. For the previous example which only focused on the next TD, please use http://jsfiddle.net/v2Tdn/1/ .

Comment: You should probably mention that this code requires JQuery, as `$` isn't a part of the standard ECMAScript.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Disclaimer added. Downvote removed?

Comment: Irritating how people jump on the downvote button when the answer is perfectly valid and just forgets to mention jQuery is needed. Just add the comment and upvote, especially since this answer works, and has the fiddle to proof it!

Answer (score 1):

I've built a fully editable table "Grid" in JS and HTML before.. and logic behind it simply is as following:
1- in your table after you layout all your cols, add an action col and add a "edit" link in each row that points to an Edit function, in this Edit link pass the row index so.. it will look like that:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='EditBtn' onclick='Edit("+ rowIndex +")'>Edit</a>"
```

2- your Edit function will simple loop on your columns using that rowIndex and replace the  text values with a text box tag

```
"<input type='text' id='nominal' id='editableField' >" + tdTxt + "</input >"
```

Just avoid making the "Edit" column Editable

now, you should have a fully editable row.. 
on last thing, is to Add beside the "Edit" link a "Cancel" link that will loop again on the Row columns like the Edit link and Replace the Text tags with a Span or just pure html with the "" original values..

You may wonder how I will have the origianl td values, well in this case we added a hidden field that carrys the td value, so when the user click cancel after edit. we get the cell original value before edit,

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qft8S/2/) showing how to capture and `preventDefault` action on enter key press.

Here's the code that does the trick:

```
$('table').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == 13) {
            console.log("Enter pressed");
            e.preventDefault();
            //    focus 'td' in next column using jQuery '.focus()'
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: You should probably mention that this code requires JQuery, as `$` isn't a part of the standard ECMAScript.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Don't you think editing the answers to say they use jQuery and not vanilla JavaScript would had sufficed? Or for that matter just leaving a comment? Downvoting is to be used when the suggested answer is downright 'not useful'. And, you mister seem to be on a spree of down-voting. In any case, the other answers to this question have been edited to mention the use of jQuery. Consider revoking your down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that 'contenteditable' is making your markup behaving like a `<textarea>`. Normally, people press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to skip from a form field to another.

Using jQuery javascript library, you can read the keyboard for <kbd>enter</kbd> key, javascript it to 'escape' the edition by setting focus somewhere else, perhaps the next td with contenteditable. :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $editableTd = $('td[contenteditable]');
    $editableTd.bind('keypress', function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == 13) {
            var ind = $editableTd.index(this); //check next td to target
            $editableTd.eq(ind + 1).focus(); //set focus to it
            e.preventDefault(); //do 'nothing'
        }

    });
});
```

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfj4J/)

Comment: You should probably mention that this code requires JQuery, as `$` isn't a part of the standard ECMAScript.